# Using Dojo and jqgrid with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, jqgrid, dojo

I am using dojo and jqgrid library with codeigniter. it working fine. I have implemented dojo for ui and jqgrid for listing data from database. it almost working fine. when I took operations like , insert , update, delete, the jqgrid is not relecting chanes. menas it is not reloading data from database. Here are my code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: sitepath+"factory/addfactory",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{factory_name:factory_name,address:address,city:city,state:state,country:country,pincode:pincode,active:active},
        success:function(){
        }
    });
dijit.byId('dialogAddFactory').hide();
reload_grid(); ]

function reload_grid()
{
    $("#factorylist").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
}
```

above ajax call is for insert opetration in database.
and the reload_grid() function is for reload the jqgrid.
it will show me in console that data are perfect but it is not showing me in grid.
sometimes it is showing me and some times it is not.

Comment: using firebug? shows you an error? what happens if you put the trigger directly in the action  ajax?

Comment: Do you have a public URL for us to look at?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that reload_grid() execute before ajax response. either use async or reload the grid after ajax response.

**method - I : use async**

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: sitepath+"factory/addfactory",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{factory_name:factory_name,address:address,city:city,state:state,country:country,pincode:pincode,active:active},
        success:function(){
        }
});
dijit.byId('dialogAddFactory').hide();
reload_grid();
function reload_grid()
{
    $("#factorylist").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

**method - II : reload the grid after ajax response.**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: sitepath+"factory/addfactory",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{factory_name:factory_name,address:address,city:city,state:state,country:country,pincode:pincode,active:active},
        success:function(){
            dijit.byId('dialogAddFactory').hide();
            reload_grid();
        }
});
function reload_grid()
{
    $("#factorylist").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be good to refresh grid then you resive success responce from server, and add some debug out

```
    success:function(data){
       $("#factorylist").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
       console.log('ok'); 
    }
```